# Codeigniter use lang->line in a helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I am trying to do, is use the `language helper` inside diff helper:

```
$this->CI =& get_instance();


if (!function_exists('execute_dynamic_constants')) {
    function execute_dynamic_constants()
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var promptMsg = '<?php $this->CI->lang->line('success');?>';
        </script>
        <?php

    }
}
```

but it seems that the`language helper` is not being loaded. When I am loading it inside the `$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'language', 'form', 'Functions','DynamicJs');`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing an echo to print the line to the HTML.

```
var promptMsg = '<?php echo $this->CI->lang->line('success');?>';
```

Also, CI 2 docs state that $CI->lang->line() is deprecated in favor of lang(); http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/language.html

This is how I made your example work:

```
if (!function_exists('execute_dynamic_constants')) {
    function execute_dynamic_constants()
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var promptMsg = '<?php echo lang('success');?>';
        </script>
        <?php

    }
}
```

I dropped the $CI reference, since it is no longer needed if the lang(); from the preloaded language helper is used.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: The ellislab link is out dated now please use links from http://www.codeIgniter.com/docs and ellislab does not deal with codeIgniter any more.